# Installing Ubuntu 22.04.3 on SSD+HDD

Tags: system-installation, hard-drive, ssd, laptop

I am new to ubuntu  and I wanted to install ubuntu on my laptop but i am having a problem . I have a laptop with 2tb HDD  with windows install in it  and i just bought a 256gb SSD. Now the problem is I want to install ubuntu on the SSD  (nothing in it brand new) and remove windows from HDD ( I am ok with formatting it also) and use it for storage( like movies and document) but I don't know how to do it. Can anybody tell me how to do it easily.

Comment: See if my answers works for you. It is fairly easy to do (but that might be because I have been doing this for well over a decade ;) )

Answer (score 1):

Turn the machine off. Add the SDD to your system. insert the installer USB, and boot. If the installer shows up continue. If it boots into windows reboot, enter bios, go to the option that lets you pick the boot order and pick your USB (switch it back to your SDD when you are done with the installer)

When the desktop shows up connect your network. This allows you to use the internet during the install. It will be slow but very handy if you have only this one system, run into trouble and need to look up something.

The installer section where you partition set your SSD to mountpoint `/` and your HDD to your personal directory. Set both to "ext4" and "format" and let it install. If you need a dual boot with Windows you could also format the HDD to NTFS or just mount it and remove the contents later.

After installation all you need to do is change permissions of your mountpoint (`sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /{mountpoint}/`) and alter one file: `~/config/user-dirs.dirs`. It holds the directories create in `/home/$USER/`. It accepts 2 methods: relative to /home/ or absolute. That last one allows to point it to the mountpoint of your HDD. My version:

```
# This file is written by xdg-user-dirs-update
# If you want to change or add directories, just edit the line you're
# interested in. All local changes will be retained on the next run.
# Format is XDG_xxx_DIR="$HOME/yyy", where yyy is a shell-escaped
# homedir-relative path, or XDG_xxx_DIR="/yyy", where /yyy is an
# absolute path. No other format is supported.
# 
XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="/discworld/Desktop"
XDG_DOWNLOAD_DIR="/discworld/Downloads"
XDG_TEMPLATES_DIR="/discworld/Templates"
XDG_PUBLICSHARE_DIR="/discworld/Public"
XDG_DOCUMENTS_DIR="/discworld/Documents"
XDG_MUSIC_DIR="/discworld/Music"
XDG_PICTURES_DIR="/discworld/Pictures"
XDG_VIDEOS_DIR="/discworld/Videos"
```

/discworld is my hdd. Either reboot or press F5 on the desktop to have it reload. If you have icons (mine as an example) `/discworld/Desktop` those will show.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation . Now I have just one question that I install games or other software and games through steam will they install in my SSD or HDD because I want install games on my SSD and lightweight software on my HDD.

Comment: Steam lets you choose where to install game files.  Anything from apt or snap will go to / and not the hdd.